# How can I get 3 thread pool using multiple datasource?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, concurrency, stream

Help please.
I have a class that is responsible for config to the database:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "spring")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @NotEmpty
    private Map<String, Database> databases;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Database {
    @NotEmpty
    private String url;

    @NotEmpty
    private String username;

    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String driverClassName;
    }
}
```

There are 3 databases in my **application.yml** file:

```
spring:
    H21:
      url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
      username: sa
      password:
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    H22:
      url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test2
      username: sa
      password:
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    H23:
      url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test3
      username: sa
      password:
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

I have a Map, in which when the application is initialized (I use the **@PostConstruct** method for this), all datasource from the application.yml file are included.
Ok. It's fine.
But I have a problem.

In the doCheck method method, I create a thread pool = the number of datasource in the Map (3 items) and foreach the Map and call method to the databases.

The line ***template.query(query, ResultSet::getRow)*** in **performQuery** method must be called in parallel for all databases, not sequentially.
It's very important for me.

If in the application.yml file 3 databases, it does not work (the application starts and when I send a request through Postman the program waits for a long time and nothing happens).
If in the application.yml file 2 databases, then everything works.
I read on the Internet that parallelStream() creates only 2 thread pools. Therefore, it works for me when there are only 2 databases in the application.yml file and they are working in parallel.
But when there are 3 bases in the application.yml file, it does not work for me.

```
@Service
@Log
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DBServiceImpl implements DBService {

    private final DatabaseConfig databaseConfig;

    private Map<String, JdbcTemplate> templates;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    templates = databaseConfig.getDatabases()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> createJdbcTemplate(entry.getValue())));
    }

    private JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate(DatabaseConfig.Database database) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .url(database.getUrl())
            .username(database.getUsername())
            .password(database.getPassword())
            .driverClassName(database.getDriverClassName())
            .build());
    }

    public synchronized PerformanceCheckResult doCheck(String query) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    PerformanceCheckResult checkResult = PerformanceCheckResult
            .builder()
            .queryExecutionResults(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>())
            .checkStartedAt(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(templates.size());

    List<QueryExecutionResult> queryExecutionResults = executor.submit(() -> templates
            .entrySet()
            .parallelStream()
            .map(entry -> performQuery(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), query))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())).get();

    checkResult.setQueryExecutionResults(queryExecutionResults);
    checkResult.setCheckEndedAt(System.currentTimeMillis());
    checkResult.setTotalCheckDurationTime(getDurationMillis(checkResult.getCheckStartedAt(), checkResult.getCheckEndedAt()));
    return checkResult;
    }

    private QueryExecutionResult performQuery(String databaseName, JdbcTemplate template, String query) {
    QueryExecutionResult executionResult = QueryExecutionResult
            .builder()
            .databaseName(databaseName)
            .queryExecutionStartedAt(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();
    template.query(query, ResultSet::getRow);
    executionResult.setQueryExecutionEndedAt(System.currentTimeMillis());
    executionResult.setQueryExecutionDurationTime(
            getDurationMillis(executionResult.getQueryExecutionStartedAt(), executionResult.getQueryExecutionEndedAt()));
    return executionResult;
    }

    private Long getDurationMillis(Long start, Long end) {
    return end - start;
    }

}
```

I really need your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `invokeAll` on the executor rather than `submit`.
This code is just submitting one task to the executor, which then calls `parallelStream`:

```
List<QueryExecutionResult> queryExecutionResults = executor.submit(() -> templates
        .entrySet()
        .parallelStream()
        .map(entry -> performQuery(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), query))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())).get();
```

You don't need `parallelStream`; just create a collection of tasks and use the executor's `invokeAll` method, which will try to parallelize as much as it can.

Here's a sketch of what I mean:

```
class Query implements Callable<String> {
    public String call() {
        String s = ""; // do some database query that returns a string
        return s;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var queries = List.of(new Query(...), ...);
    var exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(queries.size());
    var futures = exec.invokeAll(queries);

    for (f : futures) {
        f.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me please ? If I understood you correctly, I need to transfer the list from my tasks to invokeAll method (i.e. a list of requests to the databases).
but how can I add them to the list if they have not yet been completed?
I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: The executor service's `invokeAll` method allows you to submit a bunch of tasks, and it will execute them with as much parallelism as it can, until they are all complete. There are two ways that Java lets you represent a chunk of code that you want to run: `Runnable` and `Callable`. The difference is that `Callable` returns a result. So you need to provide the executor service a collection of `Callable` instances, each of which will run one of your queries. You'll get back `Future` instances, on which you can call `get` which will block until the task is complete.